# Seeking plugin for QGIS to create iso-distance polygons longer than 120km

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, software-recommendations, isochrone

I'm new on QGIS and I have been using the ORS plugin to create isochrones and iso-distance polygons. However, through Openroute Service I cannot create iso-distances longer than 120km.

Is there any other plugin to overcome the limit of 120km?